# multilingual domain SEO sitemaps and redirects

Tags: redirect, seo, multilingual

I have a site with .it and .com domains. At the moment the site is in Italian only, but it will be in english in the near future.

What's the best approach to handle .com domain? Should I use .com as principal in Italian and redirect .it on .com or viceversa? Should I build the site map with .com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilites:

- use .it for the Italian version, use .com for the English translation
- use one domain for both languages, redirect (301) the other one

  - use language tag in subdomain (`it.example.com`, `en.example.com`)
  - use language tag in URL path (`example.com/it/…`, `example.com/en/…`)

In all cases you should provide a language switcher (with `hreflang` and `rel` `alternate`) on each page (linking to the translation of that page).

If you use both domains or if you use one domain with several subdomains, you may create a separate sitemap for each site (`it.example.com/sitemap.xml`, `en.example.com/sitemap.xml`). If you use only one domain and the language tag in the URL path, you may create one sitemap for all languages (`example.com/sitemap.xml`).

Comment: I'm redirecting .com on .it as I'll intend to open up an english version in the near future. thanks.